# How does Linux kernel know when to use memory buffer/cache?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, cache, buffer

When we do a `find` in linux, I am guessing the kernel will store the result into buffer/cache. Let say after an hour, some changes of the folder and files happened, so my question is, when we do the next `find`:

i) Will the kernel get the wrong old result stored in buffer/cache ?

ii) How does kernel know there already some changes of the folder and files and it can't use back the result from the buffer/cache ? Is it doing a comparison between the new result and old result ? Wouldn't this even take up more time ? If not, how the kernel achieve such intelligent choice ?

iii) Do we ever need to worry about dropping the cache (i.e. : `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) to get the latest result of our operation let say `find` ? or there are some scenario where we need to do such thing ? (although I feel we shouldn't need to, but just want to make sure)

iv) Let say there is a scenario where some cron script run a command (may be `grep` a very huge file) that causing to taken up most of the resource of the server. We kill that process and truncate that huge file. That cron job then run again after few minutes. Do we need to drop the buffer/cache in order to avoid the next `grep` getting the huge file content result stored in it to avoid it hang the server again ? (sorry if this question sound too silly to you)

Comment: The system maps buffers directly to their corresponding cache entry.  The cached version is **always** accurate, sometimes more than the disk's version if the buffer hasn't yet been flushed.  It is a common mistake to think that the amount of memory taken by the cache could slow down their machine or cause out of memory problems, but that's not the case.  The kernel will always prioritize any request to memory and flush the required amount of cache to balance the system.

Comment: A `grep` should normally not be able to hang a server.  The only case I could imagine is if you have a single core CPU and a complex regular expression.  The solution if that's similar to your case, is to run it on low priority with `nice`.

Comment: @julie: "sometimes more than the disk's version if the buffer hasn't yet been flushed" -> what does the 'more' here mean ?

Comment: @julie: " It is a common mistake to think that the amount of memory taken by the cache could slow down their machine or cause out of memory problems"-> I understand about this :) My question is not concern about out of memory, but the integrity of the data stored in buffer/cache. Thanks for reminding us about it though,appreciated :)

Comment: The system cache is at the core of the filesystem IO.  The buffers allocated there are used directly for read and write operations to the disk.  So there's no question about integrity since what is in the cache is exactly what should be there at any moment.

Comment: @julie: Thanks for the response. Then how about this one -> 
 "The cached version is always accurate,sometimes more than the disk's version if the buffer hasn't yet been flushed" -> what does the 'more' here mean ?

Comment: Oh that means that the operating system does not always immediately write the last update to the disk.  Doing so might slow down other operations.  This is why you must always unmount a partition before you remove the disk.  Similarly, on Windows, you have to `safely remove hardware` (or `eject` which is equivalent).  It forces the system to empty its unwritten buffers to the disk.

Comment: @julie: I see ! So when we do `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, we also flush the kernel buffer, and force it to write the last modification on the file to the disk ? Is this buffer only apply to a 'write' operation ?

Comment: Forcing the OS to flush its buffers to disk is a separate operation that can be called with the [`sync` command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync).  When you send a directive to drop the caches, it is not taken as an order and does not guarantee that the buffers will be flushed to disk immediately.  The buffer is mapped to a portion of the FS so it is for read and write.